# Error while running flutter app on android emulator (Mac OS Intel Based)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The error that I am running into while running my flutter app is as follows:

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this error as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error I did the following:

1. Ran flutter clean in terminal
2. Deleted pubspec.lock file
3. Ran flutter pub get in terminal

and the error got solved and started working again. Even there was some error in iOS too which got resolved as well by using these steps.